# How do I change login info on my kindle?

Tags: kindle

I read from another question on here that Amazon will automatically register your user/kindle info when you order from them. If that's so, my husband bought me this as a gift and he has nothing on his kindle account. How can I change this to my account? Will I have to repurchase all books?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the same from the settings option of you device. Go to the settings and update the information.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-manage-your-kindle-fire-hds-amazon-account.html

http://www.technipages.com/kindle-fire-how-to-change-stored-email-password

If you still face any issue, I would recommend to ask the Amazon customer care.

Answer (score -1):

You can do by visiting the My Account section of Settings.

Comment: Any further information you can offer, like giving a walkthrough of which menus to go through, or screenshots, would make this a much more compelling answer.